# Django hiding an item if object == None

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template i'm trying to hide a paypal button if the email item is None.

```
{% if object.email == None %}
     <h1>Nothing here </h1>
      {% else %}
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{ object.email }}">
     </form>
     {% endif %}
```

After testing by not entering the email in my form, the button still shows and the 'Nothing here' is not showing.

Comment: You normally filter in the view, not in the template. Can you provide details of the template? Note that if you do not enter anything that is *not* per se `None`, but can be the empty string depending on how you configured your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
{% if not object.email %}
     <h1>Nothing here </h1>
{% else %}
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{ object.email }}">
     </form>
{% endif %}
```